# Cocoa app; open file (pdf) in Preview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a file path to a pdf and I want it to open in Preview. Also, I want finder to launch highlighting the file.

On iOS I would do:

```
UIApplication app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app openURL:url];
```

But I have no idea what's the alternative in Cocoa app.
Thanks

Comment: Funny, I just wanted to ask that question yesterday evening. I'll try to find a solution but I think it's best to use the PDFKit. You can never be sure if Preview is installed on your user's mac.

Comment: Preview is an OS X app. It's not installed but always included.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look at NSWorkspace

```
           NSString* path = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:installerPath.str() length:installerPath.dataLength() encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
             [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:path];
             [path release];
```

Comment: You should ignore the first line of code! That's absolutely superfluid and kind of wrong (don't use UTF-16)!