# How to open an image in Preview, double clicking NSImageView?

Tags: cocoa, image, core-data

I have a NSImageView (in an image well) bound to an attribute of an Entity. This attribute is binary data, so I'm using a Value Transformer (`NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData`). It works properly, but I want to be able to double click the image and have this image opened in Preview. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the image in Preview, I'm pretty sure you need to save it to disk first, as Preview opens *files*. You can use this `NSImage` category method I wrote to write out a JPEG of your image:

```
@implementation NSImage (DFAdditions)

- (void) saveAsJpegWithPath:(NSString *)filePath {
    NSData *imageData = [self TIFFRepresentation];
    NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];

    CGFloat compressionFactor = 0.8
    NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:compressionFactor]
                                                           forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
    imageData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:imageProps];
    [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];        
}

@end
```

If you want a lossless TIFF representation, you could reduce it to a one-line implementation:

```
- (void) saveAsTiffWithPath:(NSString *)filePath {
    [[self TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
}
```

---

To open it in Preview after you've saved it, I would take a look at the answer here: [Cocoa app; open file (pdf) in Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7791508/105717)

It describes how to open a PDF, but it should be the same for any file. Also, I agree with the first comment on the answer: ignore the first line, and use a regular string. Basically, look at the documentation on [`NSWorkspace`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html). As mentioned by Rob Keniger below, you probably want `-openFile:withApplication:`.

Comment: In particular, have a look at the `openFile:withApplication:` method.

Comment: Hi, I'm still a little confused here. I'm using core data, so when I drag an image to the imageView, it's automatically inserted into the current managedObject in managedObjectContext. So, using NSImage *img = [myImageView image]; I get the image object. Can I open this object directly? Do I need to create an URL to it? thanks again.

Comment: Updated with input from above comments. @RobKeniger, I included your tip.

Comment: Thanks @Dov, You really helped me, and I get it working. I still think that it would be simpler if I could open the image without saving it to file, once it is already saved in the entity. Am I totally wrong? thanks again

Comment: Like I pointed out, you're asking Preview to open something other than a file on disk, and as far as I know, it's not designed to do that.